# Implementing min of 3 numbers in Mic-1 macro code

Tags: algorithm, mic-1

I have the following algorithm to find a minimum of three input numbers:

```
min(a,b,c):
   x := a
   if b < x then x := b
   if c < x then x := c
   return x
end min(a,b,c)
```

I'm trying to implement a Mic-1 micro code following the algorithms above:

`OP1, OP2, OP3 = any 16 bit 2s complement value`

```
OPRES: 0
      .LOC 50
main: LODD OP1: push
      LODD OP2: push
      LODD OP3: push
      CALL min:
      INSP 2
      STOD OPRES
      HALT
min:  LODL 1; OP1
      SUBL 2; OP2 - OP1
      JPOS op1small
      SUBL 3; OP3 - OP1
      JPOS op1small
op1small: 
      LODL 1
      RETN ; OP1
```

I'm pretty new to Mic-1 and would like to get any input on this Mic-1 code above. Is there a better or shorter way I can find a min of three numbers in Mic-1? Please advise.